# Dagger2 Set up in Java with Ant in Eclipse

Tags: java, ant, dagger-2

I am having trouble in setting up Dagger 2 sample cofee app in Eclipse using Ant. We have huge source code built using Ant so we cannot switch to maven. And I can find no sources anywhere which explains how to do that.

I have created a sample project, included all the dependencies and compiled. But, how do I generate the auto generated code of Dagger and reference it.

For example when I do

```
CoffeeShop coffeeShop = DaggerCoffeeApp_CoffeeShop.builder().build();
```

Compiler in eclipse complains that DaggerCoffeeApp_CoffeeShop cannot be found.

Can somebody please help with providing me a way to set up Dagger2 with Ant?

Thanks.